# Assembly definition can't resolve namespaces from external packages

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a new project with Unity. In the project settings I set the field `Root namespace` to `Assets`.

I'm using the external package [Entitas-Redux](https://github.com/jeffcampbellmakesgames/Entitas-Redux/wiki/Installation#install-via-git-url) by installing it via Git url. In the code I will then have access to additional classes from the Entitas-Redux namespace.

I want to create unit tests for my scripts located in the `Scripts` folder, so I created a "Tests Assembly Folder" from the context menu. The current folder structure is

[image]

I get a warning that it couldn't find any test. So I have to tell the assembly definition `ScriptTests` where to search for the scripts.

That's why I added another assembly definition

[image]

Now I can associate the scripts assembly definition with the scripttests assembly definition. The problem is that the scripts assembly definition can't find the external package namespace anymore

[image]

How to fix this?

Should I remove the scripts assembly definition and add the scripts located in the scripts folder with another approach?

Comment: You have to reference the required Assemblies in your Test assembly definition see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html#reference-and-assemblies and https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html#reference-another-assembly

Comment: @derHugo, yes I think Everts answer helped me. But do you know the answer for my question in the comment section? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657685/assembly-definition-cant-resolve-namespaces-from-external-packages#comment116087233_65658087

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test asm can only test scripts that are in asm themselves.

I would suggest to move the test folder up to Assets so there is no collusion.

Then, looking at your hierarchy, you could add an asm to Sources. At that point if anything in Sources is using code outside of it, you'll have to add the assembly reference to the asm for that module.

Finally, you add Sources.asm to the test asm and your code is visible to the test.

Comment: thanks for your help, I created a `Sources` assembly definition now. Since I'm using Entitas-Redux and this makes use of Genesis I think I will have to add EVERYTHING from the list? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQLuo.png Simply adding Entitas-Redux was not enough

Comment: ok seems so ... everything from ER + Genesis